# In laravel How to validate password

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-5.4

I created a user with encrypted password.(bcrypt(password))

In rest api I am getting md5(password) [from app]
How to validate both the password?

```
\Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)
```

NOT WORKING

Comment: Those are 2 different one way hashes. There is no direct way to compare them.

Comment: You need to have the plain password to check against the hash.

Comment: @SVM In your case, `$request->password` is also hashed?

Comment: In website (already built), Registration uses bcrypt password
Now apis are built in plain JS, sending me md5 of password.
Should I change  website Registration bcypt to md5 (In that case all users need to change password )
Is there any other approach  to handle it

Comment: Nooo, MD5 is well known to be insecure.

Comment: Can I use bcrypt (that I used in Laravel project) in javascript apis?

Comment: @SVM Did my answer bring clarity to your issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to compare the actual password in Laravel. Laravel never store your password as plain text but a hashed version + salt, so you can check the plain version of the password against the hashed stored version using the `Hash::check` method:

```
// original password
$password = 'my-password';

// hashed password
$hashed_password = bcrypt($password);
// something like: "$2y$10$XFs6ocWUaiiB99QvLwTuhOuABIq71D13LmpFdeISh7RsC.SsAthHG";
```

The hashed version is the one stored.

If you want to check if the validation of a password:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

// ...

$passed = Hash::check($password , $hashed_password); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not compare passwords encrypted by different ways. You need the plain password. I guess you are trying to make a seamless access for users in your platform in order to avoid the user do two times login (in your system and the api provider system) Am I correct?

In that case, probably you need to think in other way to approach it.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 9 i make like this,

1. first import

> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

2. in rules() function

> ```
> return [
>             'password' => ['required', function ($attr, $value, $fail) {
>                 $user = User::where('email', $this->request->get('email'))->first();
>                 if ($user && !(Hash::check($value, $user->password))) {
>                     $fail('The ' . $attr . ' is invalid.');
>                 }
>             }],
>         ];
> ```